# Line Integral By Parts

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

On the forum, there was the question regarding the same topic, namely, integration by parts for line integrals. With your help, I am going to close the question completely, lest others would ask it once more. My questions are in the end of the post.

Q: More precisely, could integration by parts be applied to multiple integrals?

When $n = 1$, we obtain the famous formula

$$\int_a^b u \frac{dv}{dx} dx = u\left(b\right)v\left(b\right)- \\ - u\left(a\right)v\left(a\right)  - \int_a^b v\frac{du}{dx}dx $$

Originally, this follows from the simple differential identity

$$ d\left(u\left(x\right) \cdot v\left(x\right) \right) = udv+vdu$$

Integrating this over $[a, b]$ where $0<a<b$, we arrive at the formula above. Remember $d\varphi\left(x\right) = \frac{d\varphi}{dx}dx$.

Now I would like to generalize this up to the double integral. For that, we consider simple set $[a, b] \times [c, d]$ which is the sauare $a \le x \le b \wedge c \le y \le d$ where $\wedge$ means logical AND. One considers the simplest multiple integral

$$ I = \int_a^b \int_c^d u\left(x, y\right) \frac{\partial v\left(x, y\right)}{\partial x} dxdy$$

The idea has been already shown. One is going to have to apply the stantard formula integration by parts to the inner integral.Then

$$ I = \int_c^d \left(u\left(b, y\right)v\left(b, y\right) - \\ - u\left(a, y\right)v\left(a, y\right) - \\ - \int_a^b v\left(x, y\right) \frac{\partial u\left(x, y\right)}{\partial x}dx \right)dy$$

The first integral is then converted into the line Integral of the first kind. The other one is double integral. To make the formula more understandable, one may consider the following idea: one discerns that the first integral is

$$\int_c^d \left(u\left(b, y\right)v\left(b, y\right) - \\ - u\left(a, y\right)v\left(a, y\right) \right)dy = \\ = \int_c^d u\left(b, y\right)v\left(b, y\right) dy - \\ - \int_c^d u\left(a, y\right)v\left(a, y\right) dy $$

Now recall that $d\vec{r} = (dx, dy)$ and that

$$ \int_{\gamma} \varphi\left(x, y\right) d\vec{\Gamma} = \int_c^d \varphi\left(x\left(y\right),y\right)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}dy$$

Now put

$$ \cos \theta = \frac{dx}{d\Gamma} \\ \sin \theta = \frac{dy}{d\Gamma} $$

And note that

$$ d\Gamma = \sqrt{\left(dx\right)^2 + \left(dy\right)^2} = \\ = d\Gamma \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\Gamma}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{d\Gamma}\right)^2} \equiv d\Gamma$$

where the last equality was justified by the trigonometric identity. Using these, one gets the relationship between the line integrals of the first and second kinds:

$$\int_\gamma a\left(x, y\right)dx + b\left(x, y\right) dy = \\ = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \left(a\left(x\left(\Gamma\right)\right), y\left(\Gamma\right)\cos \theta + \\ + b\left(x\left(\Gamma\right), y\left(\Gamma\right)\right) \sin \theta \right) d\Gamma$$

Now we must apply this to the integrals above in order to convert them into line ones. In doing so, we see that the integration is over $c \le y \le d$, with respect to the variable $y$, and of the function $u\left(b, y\right)v\left(b, y\right)$. Upon defining line Integral of the first kind, we considered the line $\Gamma$ in two-dimensional space $R_2$; each segment of it were given by

$$\Delta \Gamma_k = \sqrt{\left(\Delta x_k\right)^2 + \left(\Delta y_k\right)^2}$$

So, considering the corresponding integral sum, the line Integral was obtained. That is how one solves line integrals. For that, the line is projected onto one of axes and then the solution boils down to evaluatung the definite integral. Okay, in our problem, we seek a line which is projected ontol the axis $y$, because the integration happens there. Then introduce the angles

$$\alpha =  \left(\vec{e_x}, \vec{n} \right) \\ \beta = \left(\vec{e_y}, \vec{n} \right)$$

Where $\vec{n}$ is the normal vector and $\vec{e_{\mu}}$ is the unit vector along the axis $\mu$. In the problem, pattern of normal vectors is as follows: the first is rightward, second upward, third leftward and fourth downward. Should we wish to execute our desire for converting definite integral into line one, we acquire that the first integral may be replaced with the line integral along the line from $c$ to $d$ at $b$:

$$ \int_c^d u\left(b, y\right) v\left(b, y\right)dy = \\ = \int_{\Gamma_1} u\left(x, y\right) v\left(x, y\right) \cos \alpha d\Gamma$$

and the other integral with the line integral along the line from $d$ to $c$ at $a$:

$$ - \int_c^d u\left(a, y\right) v\left(a, y\right)dy = \\ = \int_{\Gamma_3} u\left(x, y\right) v\left(x, y\right) \cos \alpha d\Gamma$$

So,

$$ \int_{\Gamma_1} + \int_{\Gamma_3} = \int_\Gamma  $$

making the whole equation become

$$\int_c^d \int_a^b u\left(x, y\right) \frac{\partial v\left(x, y\right)}{\partial x} dxdy = \\ = \int_\Gamma u\left(x, y\right)v\left(x, y\right) \cos \alpha d\Gamma - \\ - \int_c^d \int_a^b v\left(x, y\right) \frac{\partial u\left(x, y\right)}{\partial x}dxdy$$

In fact, because the directions of vectors $\vec{e_x}$ and $\vec{n}$ coincide, then $cos \alpha = 1$. Note that the angle was introduced to make the line from $c$ to $d$ at $b$ projectable onto $y$. This may be used to generalize the region of integration to an arbitrary manifold. Similarly,

$$\int_a^b \int_c^d u\left(x, y\right) \frac{\partial v\left(x, y\right)}{\partial y}dydx = \\ = \int_\Gamma u\left(x, y\right)v\left(x, y\right) \cos \beta d\Gamma - \\ - \int_a^b \int_c^d v\left(x, y\right) \frac{\partial u\left(x, y\right) }{\partial y} dydx$$

Once more, the cosine in the integrand of the first integral is 1 because the directions of vectors $\vec{e_y}$ and $\vec{n}$ coincid; which besides,

$$\int_{\Gamma_2} + \int_{\Gamma_4} = \int_\Gamma$$

Where the first integral is along the line from $a$ to $b$ at $d$ and the other one is along the one from $b$ to $a$ at $c$.

The first application of the formulae is to justify the Green formula:

$$\iint_S \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \right)dxdy = \\ = \int_\Gamma Pdx + Qdy$$

In order to show that this is valid, we apply the formulae above to doubles integrals

$$I_1 = \iint_S 1 \cdot \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}dxdy, \\ I_2 = \iint_S 1 \cdot \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dxdy$$

Upon using them, we notice that the double integral shall be zero due to the derivative of 1 with respect to both $x$ and $y$ being zero. So, both double integrals become line ones of the first kind:

$$I_1 = \int_\Gamma Q \cos \alpha d\Gamma, \\ I_2 = \int_\Gamma P \cos \beta d\Gamma$$

So,

$$ I = I_1 - I_2 = \\ = \int_\Gamma Q \cos \alpha d\Gamma - \int_\Gamma P\cos \beta d\Gamma$$

The angle $\theta$ is once again introduced and we deduce that

$$\cos \alpha = \cos \left(\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \sin \theta = \frac{dy}{d\Gamma}, \\ \cos \beta = \cos \left(\theta - \pi \right) = \\ = - \cos \theta =-\frac{dx}{d\Gamma}$$

So, we get the right side of Green formula. Remember the domain of integration used in Green formula.

The generalization of the formula integration by parts is as follows:

$$\int_\Omega u \frac{\partial v}{\partial x_m} d^n x = \\ = \int_{\partial \Omega} uv \cos \left(\vec{e_m}, \vec{n} \right) dS - \\ - \int_\Omega v\frac{\partial u}{x_m}d^n x$$

The post is very long, so I am going to stop right now, but before doing so, I state that the following theorems are justified olr derived by the formula I have written above, following the conceptual idea:

Stokes theorem of 3D, Theorem of Divergence, theorem of curl, theorem of gradient, and identities of Green. All of them are proved by the idea above. I can show but the post has already been long! So, I must put my questions.

Q1: line integrals by parts? That is the reference to Gradient theorem! In other cases, the answer is "no!".

Q2: Suppose we wish to integrate some functions $\varphi\left(x, y\right)$ over some two-dimensional region. If this function turns out to be the exact differential of the second order, can we apply the Fundamental theorem of calculus idea? I think the answer is once more reference to theorems of Gradient and Stokes ones. According to Stokes, if that integral is turnable into line one, then according to theorem of Gradient, the answer is "yes" but in some unique cases, meaning the answer should be "no!". But does the following hold true?

$$\iint_\Omega \varphi dxdy = \iint_\Omega d^2 (\psi) = \psi|_\Omega$$

I tried it and used $\varphi = 1 - xy$ to manipulate the equality above over simple square. And then changing the domain of integration, I found out that answers differ, meaning that the formula is not valid and in fact, I provided a counterexample. But I am still curious.

Q3: I know that from the theorem of divergence we get the actual formula of integration by parts for multivariable calculus. Do you see an analogue or the idea above, not mine, differ from it?

I had been writing the post 4 hours. And I am very curious about the second question. Yet, I know that the proper generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus is Stokes one.

Comment: Feel free to make me edit the post, and point me to my conceptual mistake, so we would become better at calculus if you are not :)

Comment: the generalization of "integration by parts" is just Stoke's theorem

Comment: Notice: Using my previous question on 2D divergence theorem, which is derived by following the same idea; we may put $F = uv$ to get the idea which is set forth in the post. Also, according to Gradient theorem, which follows from the idea in the post, called integration by parts for multiple integrals; there is still a little chance to put $\varphi = \nabla (\nabla \varphi) $. However, in order to use Div theorem, there must be field function $\varphi = (a(x, y); b(x, y)) $. However, after the use of Div theorem, there must be a nice boundary.

Comment: Also: Putting $a(x, y) = Q(x, y)$ and $b(x, y) = - P(x, y)$, we get Green theorem, which is true and been proved. Maybe Divergence theorem is generalization of Green one. So, to get my Q2 work, I must define integrand properly and define two order differential. The last gets me stuck; but based on my previous comment, Q2 is answered like "under some conditions, this remains true, valid or right idea but generally not and the general idea is by Stokes".

Comment: Now I understand that Q2 must be introduced in terms f differential form to apply Stokes thereom, which is one generalized formula for Gauss, Ostrogradsky and Stokes theorems, ascribed to Vito Volterra. Then I have some thoughts and ideas on Q2.

Comment: @Masacroso Your comment makes no sense to me; yet, might I have posed an incorrect question? I have no time now but when I had, I was reading about Stokes theorem history to gain acknowledgements on the specific idea that I missed.